# uploaded file is not storing in the database in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views

i am trying to make a form where banks upload a file every month but my code is fully running with all the success alerts but neither anything is getting stored in the database nor the file is getting stored in the media folder.

> my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.
class BusinessAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    user = instance.user.user.first_name
    current_month = (datetime.now()).strftime("%B")
    return 'CIR/{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(user, current_month, filename)

class UploadFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        BusinessAccount,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    month = models.DateField()
    cir = models.FileField(null = False, upload_to=user_directory_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.user.first_name
```

> my views.py file

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
            if form.is_valid():
                file = form.save(commit=False)
                if 'cir' in request.FILES:
                    file.cir = request.FILES['cir']
                    print(file.cir)
                    file.save()
                    messages.success(request,('File is sucessfully uploaded'))
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('business:upload'))
                else:
                    messages.error(request,('Please upload a valid file!'))
            else:
                print(form.errors)
                messages.error(request,(form.errors))
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request,'upload.html',{'form': form})
```

> my forms.py file

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cir = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control-file'}))

    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile
        fields = ('cir',)
```

> and my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      {% for message in messages %}

                   <div class="alert alert-success">
                       <a class="close" href="{% url 'personal:profile_form' %}" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>

                       {{ message }}

                   </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlFile1"><h1>Upload This Month's CIR</h1></label>
          {{form.cir}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

i am a little new in django so please any body could help me please

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `instance=user` argument in the form instantiation because the instance you want to save is not a user. Also you should manually set user and month on the `UploadFile` instance:

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  # there is no instance yet!
if form.is_valid():
    file = form.save(commit=False)  # the file should be there now anyway
    file.user = request.user
    file.month = timezone.now()  # django.utils.timezone
    file.save()
    messages.success(request,('File is sucessfully uploaded'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('business:upload'))
```